# stackoverflow is occured in using loops in my code

Tags: xslt

i've the below xslt

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</meta>]]></xsl:text>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Documents and Settings\u0138039\Desktop\Per\NEW.css" type="text/css"></link>
      </head>
      <body>
        <section class="tr_chapter">
          <div class="chapter">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </div>
        </section>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="case">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="case.head"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="case.head">
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Plaintiff']"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">V</xsl:text>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-sect0">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./party.line/party[@role='Defendant']"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="case.ref.no.group | judge.line"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <div class="para">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="case.ref.no.group">
    <div class="section-sect3">
      <span class="font-style-bold">Court of Appeal</span>
      <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="case.ref.no[1]/prefix" />
      <xsl:text> Nos. </xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="case.ref.no">
        <xsl:value-of select="number" />
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="year" />
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = 2)">
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="judge.line">
    <div class="section-sect3">
      <xsl:for-each select="judge">
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text> JC</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::date.group"></xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="date.group">
    <div class="section-sect4">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./date.line/date"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//catchwords.group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="catchwords.group">
    <div class="y">
      <xsl:for-each select="catchwords/catchword">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@level=1"><br/>
            <span class="font-style-bolditalic">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">-</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each select=".">
              <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
              <xsl:if test="not(position() = last()-1)">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> – </xsl:text>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//headnotes"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="headnotes/para">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=1">
        <div class="x">
          <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <div class="m">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="para.group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para.group">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:value-of select="./heading"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::label)]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//counsel.group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="orderedlist" match="list">
    <ol class="eng-orderedlist orderedlist">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="list.item/label"/>
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="orderitempara" match="list.item/label">
    <li class="item">
      <div class="para">
        <span class="item-num">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="following-sibling::case.considered">
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </span>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::list.item"/>
      </div>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list.item">
    <xsl:variable name="a">
      <xsl:value-of select="./label"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="./label">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label|case.ref)]"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="counsel.group" name="j">
<div class="ital">
    <xsl:for-each select="./counsel.line">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">Judgment received: December 4, 2008</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ref.group"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ref.group/leg.mentioned">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:text>Legislation mentioned in the judgment</xsl:text>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ref">
      <div class="para">
        <xsl:value-of select="./citetitle"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="./leg.ptr.group/leg.ptr">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>Cases cited in the judgment</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//citetitle">
      <xsl:if test="parent::case.ref/@annotation">
        <div class="ital">
          <div class="para">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:value-of select="//citecitation"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::case.ref/@court"/>
            <xsl:text> (</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="parent::case.ref/@annotation"/>
            <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
          </div>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//judgment"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="judgment">
    <div class="section-sect1">
      <xsl:value-of select="./judge.block/heading/judgename"/>
    </div>
    <xsl:for-each select="./judge.block/para">
      <div class="para">
        <span class="new">
          <xsl:value-of select="./label"></xsl:value-of>
        </span>
        <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
      </div>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./list"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="./judge.block/para.group">
      <xsl:if test="./heading">
        <div class="section-sect1">
          <xsl:value-of select="./heading/text()"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each select="para">
        <div class="para">
          <span class="new">
            <xsl:value-of select="./label"></xsl:value-of>
          </span>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label)]"/>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./list"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="emphasis">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="citetitle">
        <span class="font-style-italic">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="./list.item"/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="./@type">
        <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@type)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <span class="{$fontStyle}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when i apply this on my below part of my xml it is giving me a stackoverflow error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<case>
<counsel.group>
            <counsel.line>Azar Irwan b Moh Arifin (AG&#x2019;s Chambers) for Public Prosecutor</counsel.line>
            <counsel.line>SK Pari (Pari &amp; Co) for first accused</counsel.line></counsel.group>
<ref.group>
        <leg.mentioned>
            <leg.ref country="India">
                <citetitle type="leg" legtype="ord">Indian Penal Code</citetitle>
                <leg.ptr.group>
                    <leg.ptr provision="s" print="yes">302</leg.ptr>
                </leg.ptr.group>
            </leg.ref>
            <leg.ref country="Malaysia">
                <citetitle type="leg" legtype="ord">Criminal Procedure Code</citetitle>
                <leg.ptr.group>
                    <leg.ptr provision="ss" print="yes">112</leg.ptr>
                    <leg.ptr provision="s" print="no">112</leg.ptr>
                                    </leg.ptr.group>
            </leg.ref>

            <leg.ref country="Malaysia">
                <citetitle type="leg" legtype="ord">Penal Code</citetitle>
                <leg.ptr.group>
                    <leg.ptr provision="ss" print="yes">109</leg.ptr>
                    <leg.ptr provision="s" print="no">299</leg.ptr>

                </leg.ptr.group>
            </leg.ref>
        </leg.mentioned></ref.group>
</case>
```

please let me know how do i resolve this error and what are the steps to be followed so that in future i don't encounter this error.
 Thanks

Comment: I tried your sample with Saxon 6.5.5 and it outputs a small sample of HTML without giving any error. Which XSLT processor do you use? Does the exact error message not indicate in which line and/or template the error occured? Usually a stack overflow means a recursion happened that consumed more stack space than available, either because of infinite recursion in the XSLT code or because of deeply nested XML input.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen i use altova xml spy, the error i'm facing is at  <xsl:apply-templates select="//ref.group"/>. Thanks for the reply, i cant paste my entire xml document as it is big, can you please ptovide your email address so that i'll email you the document, then you can paste the resolution here. Thanks

Comment: You could post your XML to PasteBin so we could all see it. I've just tried your XSLT and XML in Visual Studio and it finished without error.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe, thanks for the suggestion, here is the pastebin reference [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/bjhV8EMC).Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your XSLT contains an infinite loop. Your `para.group` template contains this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//counsel.group"/>
```

And then the template for `counsel.group` has this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//ref.group"/>
```

The template for `ref.group` has this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//judgment"/>
```

The template for `judgment` has this:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="para">
    ...
      <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::label)]"/>
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Which cascades down to apply templates on a `para.group` and then you're back at the beginning. This process goes around in circles until the stack overflows. I think you need to rethink your XSLT to figure out how to prevent infinite recursion.